# Error when open up Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I want to ask a simple question. When I open up Eclipse Juno there is a pop out error box saying that :

```
 'Running Android Lint' has encountered a problem.
  Failed.
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved! This is due to runtime error is some project. This is also might be too much of runtime error. So, you guys need to solved the problem or if the project that contains error is no longer used just delete the project.